# Изменение значения в input по нажатию кнопки

Tags: input, javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку плюс значение в input text увеличивалось на одну единицу, а при нажатии на кнопку минус значение уменьшалось, но не меньше 0.

Вот [код](http://jsfiddle.net/bunh61fb/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо ловить событие нажатия на кнопки и обновлять значение в поле.

Если использовать jQuery, то:

1. Ловить нажатия: [`.on( событие, функция)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/);
2. Получить текущее значение в поле: [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/);
3. Вписать новое значение: `.val( новое значение)`.

Итого примерно [так](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
var el = $('#number');
function change(v){
    var upd = +el.val()+v;
    el.val( upd>0 ? upd : 0);    
};
$('#max').on('click', function(){ change(1);}); // потом может поменяете на +-10
$('#min').on('click', function(){ change(-1);});
```

Comment: В принципе, обработчик на двух кнопках и не особо нужен. Сделать им один класс и :

    var num = $('#number');
    $('.minmax').on('click', function(){
        num.val( +num.val() + ($(this).index('.minmax') == 1 ? -1 : 1));
    });

Comment: @Deonis не семантично как-то. Стоит поменять кнопки местами, и юзер попадает в зазеркалье со своим UX : )

Тогда уж стоит использовать непосредственно значения кнопок – там же "+" и "-" есть, этого [достаточно](http://jsfiddle.net/bunh61fb/4/):

        var newVal = +num.val() - ($(this).val().charCodeAt(0) -44);